# How do I automatically generate new variables within a function?

Tags: python, global-variables

Is there a way I can store all of the return values from a function from each time I call it? Here is the code:

```
def workdaystart(dayoftheweek):
    starthour=input("What is your START HOUR for "+ dayoftheweek+"? ")
    print("Is that AM or PM")#Allows us to differentiate between time periods#
    print ("1. AM")
    print ("2. PM")
    print("3.I DONT WORK")
    starthoursuffix = int(input('Enter your choice [1-2] : '))

    if starthoursuffix == 1:

        starthour=starthour+"AM"
    elif starthoursuffix==2:
        starthour=starthour+"PM"
    else:
        starthour=" "
    return starthour
daysofweek=
    ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]
for day in daysofweek:
    x=workdaystart(day)
```

As you can see it runs the items in the list in the function but I then want the start hour of that day to be stored as a variable outside of the funtion.

Comment: That's what `x=workdaystart(day)` does, it stores the start hour in the variable `x`.

Comment: But it will keep being overridden. After the loop, the value of `x` would be the value of Sunday's. Create a dictionary with the days as the keys and the start hours as values

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a dictionary that maps day names to start hours:

```
starthours = {}
for day in daysofweek:
    starthours[day] = workdaystart(day)
```

Answer (score 0):

I read this question as such, you want to store **all** the start hours in a variable, while with your current code, x is overwritten everytime you loop through the function.

How about using a dictionary? You can then retrieve it according to the day at will.

```
def workdaystart(dayoftheweek):
    starthour=input("What is your START HOUR for "+ dayoftheweek+"? ")
    print("Is that AM or PM")#Allows us to differentiate between time periods#
    print ("1. AM")
    print ("2. PM")
    print("3.I DONT WORK")
    starthoursuffix = int(input('Enter your choice [1-2] : '))

    if starthoursuffix == 1:
        starthour=starthour+"AM"
    elif starthoursuffix==2:
        starthour=starthour+"PM"
    else:
        starthour=" "
    return starthour

daysofweek["monday",...]
workdaydictionary = {}

for day in daysofweek:
    workdaydictionary[day] = workdaystart(day)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of the returned `starthour` values:

```
daysofweek = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]
hours = [workdaystart(day) for day in daysofweek]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Barmar's answer is very useful. You can understand a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) or [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as mutable data structures where new values can be easily added and can be accessed by index or by key. If you want to do it inside a function, it is better to rename it clearly and to add the dictionary `starthours` as a parameter.

```
def edit_workdaystart(dayoftheweek, starthours):
    ... the same
    ...
    starthours[dayoftheweek] = starthour
    # return starthour  # can be omitted

starthours = {}
for day in daysofweek:
    edit_workdaystart(day, starthours)
```